# adding MoMu + stk to my cocos2d project causes parse issue

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c++

I am trying to follow the tutorial http://arivibes.com/realtime-audio-on-ios-tutorial-making-a-mandolin/ and when I simply added the following to my .h:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#include "Stk.h"
#include "Mandolin.h"
```

and the following to my .mm:

```
#import "mo_audio.h"
```

I get "Parse Issue Expected unqualified-id" and "Parse Issue expected ')'".  The error comes from the following line in Stk.h:

```
const StkFloat TWO_PI = 2 * PI;
```

...

I should also mention, the .h and .mm files that I added those import/includes to are not the AppDelegate or ViewController as the tutorial showed, but rather my game's main CCLayer class.

Comment: Is PI defined somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha..  The problem was that I was including both the MoMu API and Stk..  MoMu's mo_def.h also defined TWO_PI, so I modified Stk.h to:

```
#ifndef TWO_PI
const StkFloat TWO_PI = 2 * PI;
#endif
```

And that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is an issue with your Stk distribution, since in Stk.h I can read:

```
const StkFloat PI           = 3.14159265358979;
const StkFloat TWO_PI       = 2 * PI;
```

and everything should be fine. You can check what you have there.

As a workaround, try changing that `PI` into:

```
M_PI
```

or add:

```
#define PI M_PI
```

in some of your header files. But this would not explain what is happening.

Comment: it says the same thing for M_PI...  Which is really weird since Cocos2d has M_PI all over the place, and that has no errors....